# uploaded and newly created Google Spreadsheets not indexed

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

Google drive does not always index files that are in google document format - specifically spreadsheets. Searching for a field in the spreadsheet works perfectly when excel spreadsheets are uploaded and not converted, but are not searchable when uploaded and converted to a google spreadsheet.

My testing within the Google Drive web application has shown that:
    - searching for "UNIQUE1234" in the exact same document uploaded twice fails when the document is "converted" to google document format but succeeds with left unconverted (as an excel, .xlsx file).
    - searching for the same string in a newly created spreadsheet (through the drive interface) also does not return the new document.
    - these google document spreadsheets are at some point indexed as I can search some of my older documents.

The real problem is that I'm writing an application that uses the Drive SDK to search for a specific string within drive spreadsheets - and it doesn't work when the files aren't indexed. The only workaround I've seen is to have users not convert uploaded documents - but this isn't great as it is nice for them to occasionally alter uploaded fields.

My questions are: What triggers google drive to index Google documents? Is there a way to trigger indexing on a particular document? Is this a bug?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'd like to autodetect spreadsheets with particular values in user's drive accounts.